# Is there any way to open the Java Mission Control with the JVM's websphere 8?

Tags: java, websphere, jmc

I have a Websphere instance running, it runs localy with its own JVM, that is bundle on it. The issue is when I try to profile the websphere process, The JMC can't view the process, I've tried of many ways:

1. Downloading the JMC binaries
2. Installing the JMC from Eclipse
3. Running the JMC from the JDK_HOME

But none of them have worked.

Is there any way to run the JMC from the JVM that comes bundle inside the Websphere directory?
Cause I checked inside the JVM inside Websphere server and the JMC doesn't exist.

[JMC Process Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXhqt.png)

[Websphere running localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3V8P.png)

[Websphere directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y7sm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the stand alone version of JMC, which you can, e.g., download from https://adoptopenjdk.net/jmc.

That said, it may not help you. I think Websphere may be using the J9 JVM, which does not (AFAIK) support JDK Flight Recorder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In fact I downloaded the standalone version in the official site of JMC and It did'nt work
But thanks.